# creating a for-loop using Javascript?

Tags: javascript, forms, for-loop

I have a problem creating a for-loop using Javascript. It seems everyting is fine for me but still I didn't get what I want.

Take a look please to this code to understand more:

- The HTML form code:

  ```
  <form name="myform">
      <textarea name="inputtext" cols="100%" rows="10%"></textarea><br />
      <input type="radio" name="options" value="javascript" checked> Option1 <br />
      <input type="radio" name="options" value="windows"> Option2<br />
      <input type="button" value="Do it" onClick="generate();"><br />
      <textarea name="outputtext" cols="100%" rows="10%"></textarea><br />
  </form>
  ```
- The Javascript code:

  ```
  function generate() {
  var code = ""+document.myform.inputtext.value;
  if (document.myform.options[0].checked) {
      document.myform.outputtext.value = escape(code);
  }
  else {
      var result= "2- ";
      for(int i=0; i<code.length; i++) {
      //There will be some logic to decide if to add the char or not.
      result+=code.charAt(i);
      }
      document.myform.outputtext.value = result;
  }
  }
  ```

The problem is not clear for me.
**However, when I try to comment out the for-loop, everything works fine !**

Any ideas?

Comment: `int` is not a datatype in javascript. Please use a javascript debugger (like firebug on firefox) to help you out.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There is no `int` data type in Javascript (or any data types at all used to declare variables).

```
for(var i=0; i<code.length; i++) {
```

Comment: OMG! How I miss that ! Sometimes you mix between Java and Javascript. Thanks @Guffa :)

Comment: @2rk: I have the same problem jumping between C# and Javascript. I have done the exact same error several times. :)

Answer (score 0):

There is also an Object-oriented solution to this.

```
var generate = {
   loop: function() {
        var code = ""+document.myform.inputtext.value;

        if (document.myform.options[0].checked) {
            document.myform.outputtext.value = escape(code);
        }
        else {
            var result= "2- ";
            //CHANGE THE INT(I assume Java) DATATYPE TO A LOCAL VARIABLE USING THE var KEYWORD TO KEEP THE SCOPE IN THE FOR LOOP
            //RECURSION CAN BE QUICKER
            for(var i=0; i<code.length; i++) {
            //There will be some logic to decide if to add the char or not.
            result+=code.charAt(i);
        }
        document.myform.outputtext.value = result;
     }
 }

generate.loop();
```

Comment: You forgot the closing bracket for the loop.